# React app deployed with docker and nginx : /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packages

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, create-react-app

hi I am having a problem to deploy my React app ( create react app) using docker and nginx

the image is created with success : using the following script :
 `docker build -t front --network=host .`

howver when I try to run the container : `docker run -p 3000:80 front`

it is not working and I got the following message :

```
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packages version, exiting
```

my docker file :

```
FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.12 as build

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
#ARG REACT_APP_BACKENDURL
#ENV REACT_APP_BACKENDURL $REACT_APP_BACKENDURL

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.2.0 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build


# add app
#COPY . /app

# generate build
#RUN npm run  build

############
### test ###
############

# base image
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

#nginx config with react router
COPY  nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

#COPY .env /usr/share/nginx/html

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my nginx.conf :

```
server {

  listen 3000;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

}
```

any ideas what I did wrong,, also I am looking for best practices to deploy REACT APP with docker

Answer (score 0):

You should separate dockefile above into 2 dockerfile,
One for front image , one for nginx.
Then create both images. And 2 containers are belong to those images.

Expose dockerfile nodejs : `3000`

And add to nginx configuration file: `proxy_pass ip_address_nodejs_container:3000`